# Display formated values (Ks) as numeric in y-axis of ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I format the y-axis values from thousand to k and use them as numeric value in ggplot?

```
# Dummy data
data <- data.frame(
  day = as.Date("2017-06-14") - 0:364,
  value = runif(365) + seq(-140, 224)^2 / 10
)
data$value<-scales::label_number_si(accuracy = 0.1)(data$value)

p <- ggplot(data, aes(x=day, y=value)) +
  geom_line() + 
  xlab("")
ggplotly(p)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of formatting the values, format the labels via the `labels` argument of `scale_y_continuous`:

```r
library(plotly)

# Dummy data
data <- data.frame(
  day = as.Date("2017-06-14") - 0:364,
  value = runif(365) + seq(-140, 224)^2 / 10
)

p <- ggplot(data, aes(x=day, y=value)) +
  geom_line() + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::label_number_si(accuracy = 0.1))
  xlab("")

ggplotly(p)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-06-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: how can I have 4k instead of 4.0k?

Comment: Set the `accuracy=1` or remove it altogether as it is the default.